# Port based reverse proxy in Apache Web server

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I have two web applications http://app1:8080 and http://app2:3000 running on two different ports and different machines. I have to pass the applications traffic through Apache web server, http://myapp.

Now, we can configure apache webserver as reverse proxy based by mounting application to specific location.
For example,

```
ProxyPass /app1/ http://app1:8080/
ProxyPass /app2/ http://app2:3000/

ProxyPassReverse /app1/ http://app1:8080/
ProxyPassReverse /app2/ http://app2:3000/
```

After this mapping, http://myapp/app1 points to http://app1:8080 and
http://myapp/app2 points to http://app2:3000.

But, my requirement is http://myapp:8080 should point to http://app1:8080 and
http://myapp:3000 should point to http://app2:3000.
Kindly guide me how to reverse proxy the traffic on the basis of ports in apache web server.

Comment: Did you tried to create virtual host with specified port ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to create two separate Virtual Hosts, with the different ports you want.

You would need

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:3000>
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

You also will need to set Apache Listen directives for both those ports

```
Listen 8080, 3000
```